# How to read single row in CSV by a single thread in a Thread Group?

Tags: jmeter

I have a CSV file which contains 31 rows having two columns API URLs and Expected Output. I want to read a single row by each and every HTTP Request of my thread group.

Thread 1 reads row1 
Thread 2 reads row2
Thread 3 reads row3...so on

Please suggest a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) which can read the csv file.

By default when you have CSV Data Set Config, thread 1 will read row 1, thread 2 will read row 2.

If it does not work, make sure the sharing mode is 'All Threads'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default csv will have that way of access , Not sure why in your case its happening like that .

for debugging purpose add ${__threadNum} in label of your http request and check the corresponding http request and content it has sent .

by also changing the thread sharing model to ALL .

also stop thread EOF when rows are over .